# ConcurrentModificationException when using stream

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream, concurrentmodification

I'm getting

```
ConcurrentModificationException(java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1558))
```

and I suspect that I need to wait until the `HashSet(nodeRefsWithTags)` is fully populated before processing it. Or does anyone have any other advice?

The function `getTagRefs(sagerRef)` is recursively called and populates the `nodeRefsWithTags`.

```
nodeRefsWithTags = new HashSet<>();
getTagRefs(sagerRef);

List<Tag> tags = nodeRefsWithTags.stream()
            .map(nodeRef -> ((List<NodeRef>)nodeService.getProperty(nodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_TAGS)))
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .map(taggingService::getTagName)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(tagName -> tagName, Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .map(map -> new Tag(map.getKey(), map.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Can you please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce your issue? With the code you shared it is impossible to tell where the error could be.

Comment: Lambda expression quoted seems to be okay. I guess that the stracktrace that you've omitted is pointing the real problem... Also debugging the code will be your best shot to find what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where the current code modifies the set. So the object member `nodeRefsWithTags` seems to be accessible to other threads and there must be another concurrent thread modifying it. When you stream the set items, there's no guarantee that no modifications are made. There are some options:

Create a copy:

```
// At this point, you have to make sure nodeRefsWithTags is not modified by other threads.
Set<...> copy = new HashSet<>(nodeRefsWithTags);
// From now on it's ok to modify the original set
List<Tag> tags = copy.stream()...
```

Use a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html):

```
// For this option you have to make sure that no elements get removed from the map, else you
// might get an endless loop (!) which is very hard to find and may occur occationally only.
nodeRefsWithTags = Collections.newSetFromMap(new ConcurrentHashMap<>());
```

Or use ordinary synchronization (all modifications require a lock as well as the code you posted).

Comment: The purpose of the code is to process nodes from an Alfresco environment and extract their tags. It's working fine with small data but there are scenarios where there's a lot of data and the CPU gets locked at 100 %. During this scenario, it seems to have gotten stuck and never completed the process of the nodes due to the large amount. Can it be that the recursion cannot handle the large amount of depth? But shouldn't it cast a stack overflow exception if that would be the case?

Comment: @Plv90 That's a different problem. When the CPU works at 100% and the Java process gets really slow, check your RAM. It's very typical that the JVM expends all ressources on garbage collection.